# Not able to get the required ID's from a MySQL GROUP BY + HAVING query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a query various IN() clauses to get the price of product combinations. I am actually correctly getting the prices, so thats OK. But I also need some other ID's to identify to which ID's the prices belong.

As you can see IN's, they all start with a different bundle_variant_id's but the rest of the bundle_variant_id's are the same. I want to return that first (or all) of those bundle_variant_id's in the result too, but using this query, i always get '1620' as bundle_variant_id. How can i get the first bundle_variant_id in those IN's (1616, 1655, 1677, etc) or ALL of the bundle_variant_id's?

It's not an option to remove the GROUP and the HAVING or any of the WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT `HardwareProductSubscriptionInstanceLink`.`subscription_instance_id`
    ,`BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id`
    ,`HardwareProductSubscriptionInstanceLink`.`price`
FROM `wax`.`prd_providers` AS `Provider`
INNER JOIN `wax`.`prd_subscription_types` AS `SubscriptionType` ON (`SubscriptionType`.`provider_id` = `Provider`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `wax`.`prd_subscriptions` AS `Subscription` ON (`Subscription`.`subscription_type_id` = `SubscriptionType`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `wax`.`prd_subscription_instances` AS `SubscriptionInstance` ON (`SubscriptionInstance`.`subscription_id` = `Subscription`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `wax`.`prd_bundle_variants_subscription_instances` AS `BundleVariantLink` ON (`BundleVariantLink`.`subscription_instance_id` = `SubscriptionInstance`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `wax`.`prd_hardware_products_subscription_instances` AS `HardwareProductSubscriptionInstanceLink` ON (
        `HardwareProductSubscriptionInstanceLink`.`subscription_instance_id` = `SubscriptionInstance`.`id`
        AND `HardwareProductSubscriptionInstanceLink`.`hardware_product_id` = 317
        )
WHERE (
        (
            `BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id` IN (
                '1616'
                ,'1618'
                ,'1600'
                ,'1620'
                )
            )
        OR (
            `BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id` IN (
                '1655'
                ,'1618'
                ,'1600'
                ,'1620'
                )
            )
        OR (
            `BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id` IN (
                '1677'
                ,'1618'
                ,'1600'
                ,'1620'
                )
            )
        OR (
            `BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id` IN (
                '1691'
                ,'1618'
                ,'1600'
                ,'1620'
                )
            )
    AND `SubscriptionInstance`.`number_of_bundle_variants` = 4
    AND (
        (`Provider`.`enabled` = '1')
        AND (`Provider`.`visible` = '1')
        )
GROUP BY `SubscriptionInstance`.`id`
HAVING count(`BundleVariantLink`.`bundle_variant_id`) = 4
```

Current results:

(column 1 = subscription_instance_id, 2=bundle_variant_id,3=price)

```
9213    1620    331.405
9214    1620    311.57
9215    1620    291.736
9219    1620    390.909
```

Required results:

```
9213    1616    331.405
9214    1655    311.57
9215    1677    291.736
9219    1691    390.909
```

Or alternate required results:

```
9213    1616,1618,1600,1620 331.405
9214    1655,1618,1600,1620 311.57
9215    1677,1618,1600,1620 291.736
9219    1691,1618,1600,1620 390.909
```

Comment: Could you show us what your current results are and what you would like them to be?

Comment: Why do you have so many `IN` clauses? You're checking the same field each time, why not just have one `IN()`? I don't understand. can you demonstrate with a few sample rows?

Comment: To get last one desired result use `GROUP_CONCAT` so just replace or add `,GROUP_CONCAT(BundleVariantLink.bundle_variant_id)`

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.